# React Native Android Permission Denied

Tags: react-native

I am testing an app on Android 5.1.1 where the storage permission gets denied automatically. When I launch the app there is no prompt for giving permissions to the app. However, when I test the app on Android 6.0 and above with new android permissions model everything is working fine. How do I set the permissions correctly and get the permissions dialog box to prompt on app launch on android 5.0 and below?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this same issue on the location permission for android version 5.0.

This appears to be a bug in RN (we're using v0.44.0)

```
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, {
      title: 'Enable Location Tracking',
      message: 'Use your location to find nearby things',
    },
  );

  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    return true;
  }
```

For some reason, on android 5.0, granted gets set to true, instead of "granted", which is what it gets set to on 6.0+.

I worked around it by changing

```
  if (granted === true || granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, got the same issue on 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this right now, but as a guideline:

```
async function requestStorageAccess() {
  const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  )

  if (permission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log('Granted');
  }
}
```

Read:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/permissionsandroid.html

and: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I have the same async function and inside the if condition I am putting the code to download and save the image. Everything is working fine in android 6.0 and above but below that API, permission gets denied. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Do you have it set in *AndroidManifest.xml*? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: Yes I have the permissions set in AndroidManifest.xml.